# Implementing stable_partition for forward_list

Tags: c++, stl, singly-linked-list

I want to implement something similar to std::stable_partition but for forward_list of c++11.
The stl version requires bidirectional iterators, however by utilizing container specific methods I believe I can get the same outcome effeciently.

Example declaration :

```cpp
template <typename T, typename UnaryPredicate>
void stable_partition(std::forward_list<T>& list, UnaryPredicate p);
```

(while possible to add begin and end iterators, I omitted them for brevity. The same for returning the partition point )

I already worked out the algorithm to accomplish this on my own list type, but I have troubles implementing it in stl.

The key method appears to be splice_after. Other methods require memory allocations and copying elements.

Algorithm sketch :

- create a new empty list. It will hold all elements p returns true on.
- loop over the target list, add items to the true list in accordance to invoking p.
- concat the true list to the beginning of the target list.

With proper coding this should be linear time (all operations inside the loop can be done in constant time) and without extra memory allocation or copying.

I am trying to implement the second step using splice_after, but I end up either concating the wrong element or invalidating my iterators.

The question:

What is the correct use of splice_after, so that I avoid
mixing iterators between lists and insert the correct elements?

First Attempt (how I hoped it works):

```cpp
template <typename T, typename UnaryPredicate>
void stable_partition(std::forward_list<T>& list, UnaryPredicate p)
{
    std::forward_list<T> positives;
    auto positives_iter = positives.before_begin();

    for (auto iter = list.begin(); iter != list.end(); ++iter)
    {
        if (p(*iter))
            positives.splice_after(positives_iter, list, iter);
    }

    list.splice_after(list.before_begin(), positives);
}
```

Unfortunately this has at least one major flaw: splice_after inserts after iter, and the wrong element is inserted.

Also, when the element is moved to the other list, incrementing iter now traverses the wrong list.

Comment: I think you should just post your code so that we can see what you're doing.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @UKMonkey Added the original code.

Comment: @manni66 I tried to clarify, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having to maintain the preceding iterators for `std::forward_list::splice_after` makes it a bit trickier, but still pretty short:

```
template<class T, class UnaryPredicate>
std::array<std::forward_list<T>, 2>
stable_partition(std::forward_list<T>& list, UnaryPredicate p) {
    std::array<std::forward_list<T>, 2>  r;
    decltype(r[0].before_begin()) pos[2] = {r[0].before_begin(), r[1].before_begin()};
    for(auto i = list.before_begin(), ni = i, e = list.end(); ++ni != e; ni = i) {
        bool idx = p(*ni);
        auto& p = pos[idx];
        r[idx].splice_after(p, list, i);
        ++p;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Usage example:

```
template<class T>
void print(std::forward_list<T> const& list) {
    for(auto const& e : list)
        std::cout << e << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
    std::forward_list<int> l{0,1,2,3,4,5,6};
    print(l);
    // Partition into even and odd elements.
    auto p = stable_partition(l, [](auto e) { return e % 2; });
    print(p[0]); // Even elements.
    print(p[1]); // Odd elements.
}
```